# Sending three list into a structure and accessing that structure

Tags: c#

Ok so i made a list and split the list three times, im now trying to put the three list into a structure but cant access the structure after i made it. here is my code below tell me what you think

```
        char[] Split1 = { ';' };
        List<String[]> Everthing = lists.Select(l => l.Split(Split1)).ToList();
        List<String> ID1 = Everthing.Select(dt => dt[0]).ToList();


        char[] Split2 = { ',' };
        List<String[]> Try = lists.Select(l => l.Split(Split2)).ToList();
        List<String> Value1 = Try.Select(dt => dt[1]).ToList();


        char[] Split3 = { ':' };
        List<String[]> Try2 = lists.Select(l => l.Split(Split3)).ToList();
        List<String> Units1 = Try2.Select(dt => dt[1]).ToList();


        //How do i get the value, this is the only way i could think of
        var FirstTry = new List<Record>();
        FirstTry.Add(new Record
        {
            ID = ID1,
            Value = Value1,
            Units = Units1
        });
}


public class Record
{
    public List<string> ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Units { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to access to fields of your structure in `FirstTry`. For example, for getting `ID` of first element in `FirstTry` you could do this:

```
FirstTry[0].ID
```